# How we can use a function which has Data agrument while we want change variable arguments names

Tags: r

sorry, my title of question may not be clear so I have to clarify my issue with following example:
suppose we have a DF data set and we want to produce a boxplot using ggplot function:

```
DF<-data.frame("A"=rnorm(20,3,0.2),"B"=rnorm(20,2,0.1),"C"=rnorm(20,2,0.3))
DF<-stack(DF)
bp <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = ind, y =  as.numeric( values) , fill = factor( ind)))
bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
bp <- bp + labs(title="My Box", x="Categories", y ="Value")
bp <- bp + theme_bw()
bp
```

My issue is when I want to have a function similar following function to produce the boxplot for each column of my categorical variables:

```
BPFunc <- function ( PDataSet,Cat, PData, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle) {

  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = Cat, y =  as.numeric( PData) , fill = factor( Cat)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()
  bp

}
```

But this function can not work and return following error.

```
BPFunc(DF,  ind  ,  values  ,"My Box","Categories","Value")

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ind' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In factor(Cat) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after several search and struggling:

```
BPFunc <- function ( PDataSet,Cat, PData, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle) {
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  PData = eval(arguments$PData, PDataSet)
  Cat = eval(arguments$Cat, PDataSet)
  PDataSet<-data.frame(Cat=Cat,PData=PData)
  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = Cat, y =  as.numeric( PData) , fill = factor( Cat)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()
  bp

}

BPFunc(DF,  ind  ,  values  ,"My Box","Categories","Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

ind is not defined, nor is values.
You don't need them if you will always use this logic

```
BPFunc <- function ( PDataSet, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle) {

  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = ind, y =  values , fill = factor( ind)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()
  bp

}
BPFunc(DF,"My Box","Categories","Value")
```

will work

Comment: Thanks Chris, But we can not apply your function on a specific column of a  dataset which has several categorical variable. I want the name of column be an argument in the function. Suppose we have another categorical variable and also another numerical variables in the dataframe! how function can be applied on them?